# Getting error root path required while using static

Tags: node.js, express

any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

> C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_global\node_modules\express\node_modules\serve-static\index.js:40
>       throw new TypeError('root path required')
>       ^
>
> TypeError: root path required
>       at Function.serveStatic [as static] (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_global\node_modules\express\node_modules\serve-static\index.js:40:11)
>       at Object. (C:\Users\joe\Downloads\fine\nodejs.js:40:40)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
>       at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
>       at bootstrap_node.js:612:3`

the only static path I am using for are.

```
app.use(express.static(publicDir));
app.use("/node_modules", express.static(nodeModulesDir));

app.post("/uploads", onUpload);
app.delete("/uploads/:uuid", onDeleteFile);
```

Comment: Because you didn't set root path?

Comment: Was my answer useful?

Answer (score 5):

you are passing variable `nodeModulesDir`, it must be set to `node_modules` or you can directly pass string as:

**Approach 1:**

```
var nodeModulesDir = 'node_modules';
app.use("/node_modules", express.static(nodeModulesDir));
```

**Approach 2:**

```
app.use("/node_modules", express.static('node_modules'));
```